# Updating $scope attributes in angularJS after post

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, post

First of all, yes i did look at other answers but they didn't do the trick for me.

I'm currently working on an `angularJS` based shopping application. After building the cart, creating the neccesary functions and building the view i would like to optimize the "cart" by creating an "no page refresh", add_to_cart function. So after some struggeling with functions like `$scope.push` and an `init()` load the cart function i got a bit stuck. The cart is build by the following code:

**Get the cart:**

```
$scope.getCartItems = function() {
    // Get the cart
    $http.get('config/cart/getCart.php', {cache: false}).then(function (response) {
        $scope.cartItems = [];
        $scope.cartItems = response.data.cartItems;
        $scope.totalCartItems = [];
        $scope.totalCartItems = response.data;
        $scope.selectedCustomer = [];
        $scope.selectedCustomer = response.data;
    });
};
```

**Add a product:**

```
$scope.addToCart = function(product, stock_available) {
    var product_id = product.id;
    var product_name = product.name.language;
    var product_price = $('span[name="combinationTotalPrice' + stock_available.id + '"]').text();
    var product_size = $('span[name="product_attributes' + stock_available.id + '"]').text();
    var product_quantity = product.quantity;
    var product_id_attribute = stock_available.id_product_attribute;

    console.log(product_id_attribute);

    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "config/cart/getCart.php?action=addToCart",
        data: {
            product_id: product_id,
            product_name: product_name,
            product_price: product_price,
            product_size: product_size,
            product_quantity: product_quantity,
            product_id_attribute: product_id_attribute
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });
    $scope.cartItems.push(request);
};
```

By clicking on a button all the data is obtained from the view and passed to the `addToCart()` function. I've checked everything and the data gets inserted. After a hard page refresh the new product is added to the cart. But i would like to remove the "hard page refresh" and use something like i've tried above: `$scope.cartItems.push(request);`.

**Update**

So after some tips from the comments i've created a service for the cart. Take a look at the updated code:

**cartService**

```
myApp.service('cartService', ['$http',function ($http, $scope) {
    return {
        getCartItems: function() {
            return $http.get('config/cart/getCart.php', {cache: false})
        }
        // any other methods for http calls;
    }
}]);
```

**cartController and function add**

```
myApp.controller('CartController', function($http, $scope, cartService) {
    $scope.getTheCart = function() {
        cartService.getCartItems()
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.cartItems = response.data.cartItems;
                $scope.totalCartItems = response.data;
                $scope.selectedCustomer = response.data;
            })
    };

$scope.addToCart = function(product, stock_available) {
        var product_id = product.id;
        var product_name = product.name.language;
        var product_price = $('span[name="combinationTotalPrice' + stock_available.id + '"]').text();
        var product_size = $('span[name="product_attributes' + stock_available.id + '"]').text();
        var product_quantity = product.quantity;
        var product_id_attribute = stock_available.id_product_attribute;

        console.log(product_id_attribute);

        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "config/cart/getCart.php?action=addToCart",
            data: {
                product_id: product_id,
                product_name: product_name,
                product_price: product_price,
                product_size: product_size,
                product_quantity: product_quantity,
                product_id_attribute: product_id_attribute
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).then(function() {
            $scope.getTheCart();
        });
    };
});
```

So everything works fine, i can even see in the network tab that the new `getCart.php` is obtained with the new data. Sadly still my `$scope` and view isn't updated.

**Update 2**

So i've taken a look at the example and i've tried some things for myself. After some tries i came to a very weird conclusion: Using an ng-click refreshData action refreshes the data through the following function:

```
$scope.refreshData = function() {
    cartService.refreshData()
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.cartItems = response.data.cartItems;
            $scope.totalCartItems = response.data;
            $scope.selectedCustomer = response.data;
        })
};
```

but calling this function directly like the example in the first answer (jsFiddle) => [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24qox02s/1/) won't refresh the view and `$scope`

```
$scope.addToCart = function(product, stock_available) {
    return cartService.addToCart(product, stock_available)
        .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
            $scope.cartItems = response.data.cartItems;
            $scope.totalCartItems = response.data;
            $scope.selectedCustomer = response.data;
        // call the get() function
        $scope.refreshData();
    })
};
```

If you have any questions please let me know in the comments

PS: creating a JSfiddle would put me back with a lot of time since all the data is obtained through the [Prestashop webservice](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Webservice+one-page+documentation)

As always, Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$http` returns a Promise. If you want data from it, you need to resolve it: `$http(...).then((res)=>{$scope.cartItems.push(res.data);});`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey  `$http({...}).then(function(response){
            $scope.cartItems.push(response.data.cartItems);
        });` returns: `$scope.cartItems.push is not a function `

Comment: was `$scope.getCartItems()` called before `$scope.addToCart(...)` ? Because it initialises the array `$scope.cartItems = [];`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Yes it is called before the `$scope.addToCart`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using wrong approach. All http calls should be made from services, not from controllers/components. 
Try to create a service for this. 
Don't forget to inject the service in your controller.
So after all there will be something like this

for example:

```
$scope.cartItems = [];
$scope.getCartItems = function() {
cartService.getCartItems()
  .then(response => {
    $scope.cartItems  = response.data; // or response
  })
}
```

register service according to the docs and add method

```
return {
  getCartItems: function() {
    return $http.get('config/cart/getCart.php', {cache: false})
  },
  // any other methods for http calls;
}
```

Comment: Could you share a full example?

Comment: Thank you for the full example. So i've created the service and added it to my controller. Everything works out fine. It's a great technique. sadly the $scope still isn't updated. Would you please take a look at the "update" section of the question?

Comment: Update is added

Comment: @Deathstorm you should have something like that 
http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/17515/ 
All http calls should be made from service even a `post` one.

Comment: Well i've included the fiddle example with some name adjustments. The console returns the new cart with the `ng-click` added data. Still the view isn't updated untill i use a hard refresh

Comment: Do i have to add something special to my view? @Maksym Shevchenko

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/24qox02s/1/ 
here is a working fiddle. Each time you click the button - it makes http call and only then pushes new item to array of calls with current index of call (starting from 0). Try it and you will see how it works.

Comment: probably need to see the view document(html) how things are rendered there